# Replacing a container that has two possible ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
function changeimage2()
{
    /*$("#container1").css({'visibility':'hidden'});*/

    $("#PicInRightTitle").css({'visibility':'hidden'});

    $("Img").click(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#container1").replaceWith($('#container2'));
            $("#container2").show();
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: false, 
                continuous: true
            });
        }); 
    });
}
```

The above code replaces container1 with container2 .It works.
But I am trying to replace a div that has container1 OR container2 with container3
Ive tried this, but it does not work.

```
    ($("#container1") || $("#container3")).replaceWith($('#container2'));
```

How can i do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This will replace `#container1` if its on the page, otherwise it will replace `#container2`

```
if ($("#container1").length > 0)
    $("#container1").replaceWith($('#container3'));
else
    $("#container2").replaceWith($('#container3'));
```

Comment: Im not quite sure how we use this .Why is length necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can use common class for those as follows:

`$('.containers').replaceWith($('#container2'));`

Comment: @priyanka: If this answer was helpful to you, then you should mark it as accepted and probably upvote.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#container1,#container3").replaceWith($('#container2'));
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! seems to work! but my code is a little complicated, im trying to implement it correctly.but thanks anyway!